# MVC 3 , DropDownList OnSelect

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, event-handling, drop-down-menu, html-helper

I have a function dropdown list. I also have two text boxes related to the dropdown list. I want the populate the  the textboxes with data from the selected object when the dropdown list changes and is initialized. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, You can use a jquery function like this:

```
<form>
  <input class="target" type="text" value="Field 1" />
  <select class="target">
    <option value="option1" selected="selected">Option 1</option>
    <option value="option2">Option 2</option>
  </select>
</form>
<div id="other">
  Trigger the handler
</div>

$('.target').change(function() {
  alert('Handler for .change() called.');
});
```